# Bison Flex linking problems

Tags: c++, cmake, bison, lex

There is a parser running on *bison* & *flex*. To build and make the whole project cmake is used.

So, from flex file I create *lexer.cpp* file and from bison file *parser.cpp* & *parser.hpp*. The code looks like this :

***lexer.flex :***

```
%{
#include "structures/RedirectionExpr.h"
// and about 8 includes like the upper one
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "parcer.hpp"

using namespace std;
%}

%option noyywrap
%option c++

%%
/* Some staff */
%%
```

***parser.ypp :***

```
%{
  #include "structures/RedirectionExpr.h"
// and about 8 includes like the upper one, like in lexer.flex

  #include <bits/stdc++.h>
  #include <iostream>

  extern "C" int yylex(void);
  extern "C" int yyparse();
  extern "C" int errors;
  void yyerror (char const *s);
  using namespace std;
%}
%union {
    /* Union types. */ 
}

// %token definitions
// %type definitions for grammar

%%
/* grammar is here */
%%

void yyerror (char const *s) { /* Some code here */ }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    do {
          yyparse();
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Before compilation, I manually create cpp files from `.flex` and `.ypp` files:

> flex -o lexer.cpp lexer.flex
>
> bison -d -o parser.cpp parser.ypp

To build all this mess, I use cmake:

***CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(parse)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(parse 
        src/structures/RedirectionExpr.cpp        
        # other includes of classes used
        src/lexer.cpp
        src/parser.cpp src/parser.hpp
)
```

So, the problem appears, when linking :

```
/usr/sbin/ld: CMakeFiles/parse.dir/src/parser.cpp.o: in function `yyparse':
parser.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `yylex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/parse.dir/build.make:294: parse] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/parse.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

As a solution I tried to add `%noyywrap` option, include `parser.hpp` into `.flex` file after than I include additional classes, put `extern "C" int yylex(void);` line into `parser.ypp` etc. But right now I have no idea how to fix it. Can you help me with it?

## Update

I solved the problem by removing `extern "C"` and leaving `int yylex(void);` part in `parser.ypp` file. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289417/c-scanner-with-flex-and-bison-undefined-reference-to-yylex-and-yytext).

Comment: The error message is clear: none of your source files **implements** `yylex` function. That function, probably, should be implemented in `lexer.cpp`, so you may open that file and search the function's definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're intending to use the C lexer API. After all, in your parser you say

```
extern "C" int yylex(void);
```

So it's a bit puzzling that you use `%option c++` in your flex file. If you do that, you will get the C++ interface, which does not include a "C" `yylex()`.

I think your easy option would be to delete that `%option` and change the declaration of `yylex` to just

```
int yylex();
```

without the `extern "C"`

If you really want to use the C++ interfaces, I believe the Bison manual includes an example of using a C++ flex lexer. It's more work but I'm sure it pays off.

Also, I'm not a CMake user but I'm pretty sure CMake does know how to compile flex/bison projects (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50830297/1566221)). It might get confused by the C++ interfaces, but it looks like it's easy to do a traditional C build.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the thing, that helped me out, was your answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289417/c-scanner-with-flex-and-bison-undefined-reference-to-yylex-and-yytext). So, I just changed `extern "C" int yylex(void);` to `int yylex(void);` what solved linker problems.

Comment: @koshachok: that is certainly a more comprehensive answer :-) I considered marking this question as a duplicate but in the end I settled for adding the detail about `extern "C"` here. Anyway, glad you got things working.